# Reordering a file, based on a second file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sort

I have a file that is out of order.I would like to reorder it by using a second file.

File 1

```
1 HD;BSkyB:11097:VC23M5O25P0S1:S28.2E:23000:2305=27:2307=NAR@4;2306=eng@106:2308;2309=eng:0:21000:2:2066:0

2 HD;BSkyB:11097:VC23M5O25P0S1:S28.2E:23000:2315=27:2316=NAR@4;2317=eng@106:2318;2319=eng:0:21020:2:2066:0

3 HD;BSkyB:11097:VC23M5O25P0S1:S28.2E:23000:2320=27:2321=NAR@4;2322=eng@106:2323;2324=eng:0:21030:2:2066:0

ITV HD;BSkyB:11097:VC23M5O25P0S1:S28.2E:23000:2305=27:2307=NAR@4;2306=eng@106:2308;2309=eng:0:21000:2:2066:0
```

And a second file

```
3 HD
1 HD
2 HD
```

I want to scan file two, and reorder file 1, and left overs get amended to the end if the file, so the end result is

```
3 HD;BSkyB:11097:VC23M5O25P0S1:S28.2E:23000:2320=27:2321=NAR@4;2322=eng@106:2323;2324=eng:0:21030:2:2066:0
1 HD;BSkyB:11097:VC23M5O25P0S1:S28.2E:23000:2305=27:2307=NAR@4;2306=eng@106:2308;2309=eng:0:21000:2:2066:0
2 HD;BSkyB:11097:VC23M5O25P0S1:S28.2E:23000:2315=27:2316=NAR@4;2317=eng@106:2318;2319=eng:0:21020:2:2066:0
ITV HD;BSkyB:11097:VC23M5O25P0S1:S28.2E:23000:2305=27:2307=NAR@4;2306=eng@106:2308;2309=eng:0:21000:2:2066:0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to say that I'm voting to move this question to Unix/Linux, as it's more about programming/scripting than about actual systems administrations. There are a lot of very knowledgeable people there and you may get some other interesting approaches in addition to the one you've already gotten.

Comment: ServerFault is not a script writing service.  In the future please include what attempts you've made to resolve your sitatuion.  Or at least add what resources you read or looked at that you were confused by.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of the file, loading each line into an array would be the easiest way to handle this. Use your index file to get an object key (reference to the item in the array) and write that line, loop, etc.

I see you tagged Linux/bash, so here is some helper info.

Bash arrays have numbered indexes only, but they are sparse, ie you don't have to define all the indexes. An entire array can be assigned by enclosing the array items in parenthesis:

```
  arr=(Hello World)
```

Individual items can be assigned with the familiar array syntax (unless you're used to Basic or Fortran):

```
  arr[0]=Hello
  arr[1]=World
```

But it gets a bit ugly when you want to refer to an array item:

```
echo ${arr[0]} ${arr[1]}
```

To quote from the man page: 
The braces are required to avoid conflicts with pathname expansion.

In addition the following funky constructs are available:

```
  ${arr[*]}         # All of the items in the array
  ${!arr[*]}        # All of the indexes in the array
  ${#arr[*]}        # Number of items in the array
  ${#arr[0]}        # Length of item zero
```

The ${!arr[*]} is a relatively new addition to bash, it was not part of the original array implementation.

The following example shows some simple array usage (note the "[index]=value" assignment to assign a specific index):

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(one two three four [5]=five)

echo "Array size: ${#array[*]}"

echo "Array items:"
for item in ${array[*]}
do
    printf "   %s\n" $item
done

echo "Array indexes:"
for index in ${!array[*]}
do
    printf "   %d\n" $index
done
echo "Array items and indexes:"
for index in ${!array[*]}
do
    printf "%4d: %s\n" $index ${array[$index]}
done
```

Running it produces the following output: Array size: 5
Array items:

```
   one
   two
   three
   four
   five
```

Array indexes:

```
   0
   1
   2
   3
   5
```

Array items and indexes:

```
   0: one
   1: two
   2: three
   3: four
   5: five
```

Note that the "@" sign can be used instead of the "*" in constructs such as ${arr[*]}, the result is the same except when expanding to the items of the array within a quoted string. In this case the behavior is the same as when expanding "$*" and "$@" within quoted strings: "${arr[*]}" returns all the items as a single word, whereas "${arr[@]}" returns each item as a separate word.

Much more info on bash arrays is found at http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays

To load a file into an array, you could use something like this using the X variable to add an index to the array, or you could, within the loop, pull a custom index.

```
#!/bin/sh

files="`cat $1`"

for x in $lines
    echo "$x"
done
```

Comment: Ok thanks, a great and through answer. I'm going to do some reading and learn about arrays. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F';' '
  NR == FNR {a[$1] = $0; next}
  {print a[$0]; delete a[$0]}
  END {for (l in a) print a[l]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Ouch. But that's clever. Want to explain it to the OP?